# how do loop over NetCDF timeseries

Tags: python, loops, netcdf4

I have some NetCDF time series data. With reading variables, I want to make a list of for global average value for each data. I wrote the code that is working, but it is not sexy. How can I write (loop) this code in better shape?

```
variables = 'name1 name2 name3 name4'.split()
name1  =[]
name2  =[]
name3  =[]
name4  =[]

for i in range (9,40):
    name1_irrY = name1_aSrc[i].mean()
    name1.append(name1_irrY)
    name2_irrY = name2_aSrc[i].mean()
    name2.append(name2_irrY)
    name3_irrY = name3_aSrc[i].mean()
    name3.append(name3_irrY)
    name4_irrY = name4_aSrc[i].mean()
    sname4.append(name4_irrY)
```

`"name"_aSrc[i,:,:]` is variable of NetCDF.

since I have a lot of files, I need to sufficient way.

Comment: Just to emphasize that if the global mean is a spatial mean over a lat-lon grid, then the use of mean() is *not* correct and weights need to be used cosine(latitude) - see this link for more details: https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/area_weighted_temperature.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the loop at all, since you can specify along which axis you want to calculate the mean. So something like this should be sufficient (this replaces the entire block of code that you posted):

```
name1 = np.mean(name1_aSrc[9:40,:,:], axis=(1,2))
name2 = np.mean(name2_aSrc[9:40,:,:], axis=(1,2))
# etc..
```

A small example with some NetCDF data that I had lying around:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

f = xr.open_dataset('u.xz.nc', decode_times=False)
u = f['u'].values

print(u.shape)  # prints: (5, 96, 128, 1)

umean = np.mean(u, axis=(1,2,3))

print(umean.shape) # prints: (5,)
```

An alternative solution is to let xarray calculate the mean over a (named) dimension or multiple dimensions. Quick example with some other data:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

f = xr.open_dataset('drycblles_default_0000000.nc', decode_times=False)

# Original file has 3 dimensions:
print(f.dims)   # prints Frozen(SortedKeysDict({'time': 37, 'z': 32, 'zh': 33}))

# Calculate mean over one single dimension:
fm1 = f.mean(dim='z')
print(fm1.dims)  # prints Frozen(SortedKeysDict(OrderedDict([('time', 37), ('zh', 33)])))

# Calculate mean over multiple dimensions:
fm2 = f.mean(dim=['z','zh'])
print(fm2.dims)  # prints Frozen(SortedKeysDict(OrderedDict([('time', 37)])))
```

`fm1` and `fm2` are again simply xarray datasets:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 37)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) float64 0.0 300.0 600.0 900.0 ... 1.02e+04 1.05e+04 1.08e+04
Data variables:
    iter     (time) float64 0.0 5.0 10.0 15.0 20.0 ... 282.0 293.0 305.0 317.0
    area     (time) float64 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 ... 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
    areah    (time) float64 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 ... 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
    th       (time) float64 304.8 304.8 304.8 304.8 ... 305.1 305.1 305.1 305.1
    th_3     (time) float64 1.246e-08 -3.435e-11 ... 7.017e-06 5.548e-05
```

Comment: It is the axis of the Numpy array over which the mean is calculated. If for a three-dimensional array you call `np.mean(array, axis=(0,1))` you get the mean calculated over the first two dimensions, so the array is reduced to the size of the third dimension. In your case, you want to calculate the mean over the last two dimensions (excluding the first one), so that's `np.mean(.., axis=(1,2))`

Comment: Ok, thank you, but I think it is not good to repeat `name1 = np.mean(name1_aSrc[9:40,:,:], axis=(1,2))` 100 times since I have 100 variables.

Comment: Are they all named `name1_aSrc`, `name2_aSrc`, etc.? Alternatively, you could simply loop over all the variables in the NetCDF file (or a sub-selection of them). Can you add a `ncdump -h` (or something similar` of your NetCDF file?

Comment: `name1` etc. is put by myself to distinguish variables, and it can be `a` or `b`. I have many different NetCDF files.

Comment: I added an alternative solution using xarray, which allows you to calculate the means over the entire NetCDF file (per variable) at once.

Comment: The OP seems to want global (spatial, I presume) means, which means that the straight use of mean in the question and also this solution would be highly inaccurate (for your file not an issue of course as your dims were z and zh).

Answer (score 0):

Note that this question asks for a "*global average value*", implying that the averaging is a spatial average over lat and lon. In that case the use of mean() in the question, and also Bart's solution above is not correct, and will lead to very inaccurate results, [see this this link for more details](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/area_weighted_temperature.html).  Bart's example file is a function of height so this is not an issue for his particular file, but I think it was for the OP.

This is an example from the xarray page on how to apply weights.

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")    
weights = np.cos(np.deg2rad(air.lat))
weights.name = "weights"
air_weighted = air.weighted(weights)
weighted_mean = air_weighted.mean(("lon", "lat"))
```

Alternatively you can use the cdo package within python

```
from cdo import Cdo
cdo=Cdo()
res=cdo.fldmean(input="in.nc",output="out.nc")
```